# react-native -cli installation error

Tags: react-native, command-line-interface, react-native-cli

I'm trying to install `react-native-cli` by using the following command:

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32>npm install -g react-native -cli
```

and I'm getting the following errors, can someone help on this matter?

```
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
D:\Programming\React.js\ProgrammingReact.jsnode_modules\node_modules\react-native -> D:\Programming\React.js\ProgrammingReact.jsnode_modules\node_modules\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\wrong-react-native.js
npm WARN react-native@0.54.0 requires a peer of react@^16.3.0-alpha.1 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @babel/plugin-check-constants@7.0.0-beta.38 requires a peer of @babel/core@7.0.0-beta.38 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules\react-native\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
```

Comment: you can ignore these warnings you app will build and run, please see there are issues with vendor builds (https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5)